# JqGrid is not showing dropdown box

Tags: jqgrid, drop-down-menu, save

I have a problem with my jqgrid. I have created a dropdown box that calls values from the database, so I use the following syntax in my colmod.

`{name:'brate_id',index:'brate_id',width:100,formatter:"select",edittype:"select",editoptions:value:<?=json_encode($brate_list)?>}   ,editable: true},`

my brate_list is

`$brate_list = $employee->get_table_for_dropdown('hr_basic_rate','brate_id','rate_hcode');`

It seems that when I place the formatter it does not show my dropdown box unless I click on the cell to select it. But when I remove my formatter it shows the dropdown box but when I am saving the data it sends the wrong datatype

(E.g. when I pass values from the database I convert Y to Yes, so when it appears in the dropdown box it is Yes, so when I try to save my data with the formatter on, it sends Y. But if the formatter is removed, it sends Yes to the database where it becomes null instead).

Is there a way to show the dropdown box in the jqgrid without affecting its saving and its format?.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `editoptions:value:` should have a { before like this: `editoptions: { value:`

Hope this helps!

```
{name:'brate_id',index:'brate_id',width:100,formatter:"select",edittype:"select",editoptions: { value:  <?=json_encode($brate_list)?>} ,editable: true},
```